# Restrict acces to a folder(and all its files and subdirectories) stored on a sd card C#

Tags: c#, directory, sd-card, rights

Hy,
is there any posibillities to restrict acces to a folder stored on an sd card?
I tried this but it doesn't work...Any ideas are welcome.
Thanks...

```
public static void setRight(string dirName,string account, FileSystemRights rights, AccessControlType controlType)
    {
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);

        DirectorySecurity dSecurity = new DirectorySecurity();// Directory.GetAccessControl(dirName);

        // Add the FileSystemAccessRule to the security settings.
        dSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, controlType));

        // Set the new access settings.
        dir.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
        Directory.SetAccessControl(dirName, dSecurity);

    }
```

Comment: You might try encrypting the files and subdirectories instead.

Comment: Sample of restrict permission on directory: http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`File.Encrypt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.encrypt) and [`File.Decrypt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.decrypt) methods. You can use recursion to encrypt directories, by encrypting all files in them.